# how to implement Facebook Account kit in flutter with custom UI

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, account-kit

I want to setup facebook account kit in my flutter app with custom UI its possible in native app. facebook official site have document only for ios and android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [flutter_account_kit 0.6.6](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_account_kit) package now allows this to be done. For custom UI, you would need to edit your styles.xml file independently, which they show [here](https://github.com/underscopeio/react-native-facebook-account-kit/commit/77df35ae20f251e7c29285e8820da2ff498d9400) - note that while it shows React Native as the project, the same principle applies to Flutter.